# How to setup/make Haproxy send read-write request based on REST method

Tags: haproxy, postgresql-cluster, patroni

How to setup/make Haproxy send read-write request coming on same port 5432 from application, to backend servers of postgres-patroni cluster based on REST method.

I have three node postgres-patroni cluster running as docker service/containers behind Haproxy.
I wanna sent read/get request coming from my-application on port 5432 to relicas of my cluster and sent write/(Delete|Post|Update) request coming from my-application also on port 5432 to master server.

I have tried to achieve it with below config. But didn't succeed as of now.

Any idea How to make Haproxy achieve above scenario.

Here is my Haproxy.cfg file

```
global
        maxconn 100

defaults
        log     global
        mode    tcp
        retries 2
        timeout client 30m
        timeout connect 4s
        timeout server 30m
        timeout check 5s
        # never fail on address resolution
        default-server init-addr none

resolvers docker_resolver
        nameserver dns 127.0.0.11:53
listen stats
    mode http
    bind *:7000
    stats enable
    stats uri /

frontend master_postgresql
        bind *:5432
        acl is_post method "POST|UPDATE|DELETE"
        use_backend backend_master if is_post
        default_backend backend_master

frontend replicas_postgresql
        bind *:5432
        acl is_get  method GET
        use_backend backend_replicas  if is_get
        default_backend backend_replicas

frontend patroni_api
        bind *:8008
        default_backend backend_api

backend backend_master
        balance source
        hash-type consistent
        option httpchk OPTIONS /master
        server postgres1 postgres1:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
        server postgres2 postgres2:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
        server postgres3 postgres3:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4

backend backend_replicas
        option httpchk OPTIONS /replica
        server postgres1 postgres1:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
        server postgres2 postgres2:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
        server postgres3 postgres3:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4

backend backend_api
        option httpchk OPTIONS /master
        server postgres1 postgres1:8008 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
        server postgres2 postgres2:8008 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
        server postgres3 postgres3:8008 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
```